# Replacing a double space with a break tag in flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a database with each row being a particular event. Every event has an associated information column. In flask I'm trying to replace double spaces in the information string with a `<br>` tag for the html document. However when I do it the naive way with `.replace('  ','<br>')` it of course only puts this into the actual text. What would be a good way of going about this issue?

Currently the relevant part of my python code looks like this:

```py
kalender = Kalender.query.order_by(Kalender.datum).all()
for k in kalender:
    if k.datum < datetime.date.today():
        db.session.delete(k)
        db.session.commit()
```

and the relevant part of the html document is only:

```html
{% for arr in kalender %}
<p>{{arr.info}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The question is unclear. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I see the `for k ...` loop, but I don't see any manipulation of `k.info` within it. Were you hoping to .replace() and commit in there? Or in the HTML `for arr ...` loop? Please clarify what you do, what you see, and what you'd like to see. You might consider defining a helper function that does the .replace(), and calling the helper within the `for arr` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string in the template and add a `<br>` tag after each part:

```py
import jinja2

s = 'Hello world  Hello world  Hello world'

template = jinja2.Template(
"""
{% for part in s.split('  ') %}
    {{ part }}<br>
{% endfor %}
"""
)
print(template.render(s=s))
```

Output:

```
    Hello world<br>

    Hello world<br>

    Hello world<br>
```

In your case, of course `s` corresponds to the `info` attribute of each `Kalendar` instance.